# How to keep blender work speed consistent as the file size gets larger?

Tags: rendering, workbench-render-engine

As I'm working on a project in blender, the speed that things work, being edit speed or any function of the system, gets dramatically slower as the file gets larger, my file is currently 237kb, and its already pretty slow, even with an intel i5 processor that usually runs my laptop extremely fast. I know working on separate parts of the project in different files can limit the issue, but it can be inconvenient and dramatically slower when all added together. I'm not completely sure how to research this topic, but are there any settings, quality settings, or workbench rendering settings I could amend to keep work speed about as fast as start speed, or is the processor simply doing the best it possibly can, as is? I apologize for any lack of proper communication regarding terms and descriptions, and I'm open to any questions.

Comment: Well, that depends entirely on your system as you say, as you struggle with 237kb, my workstation works perfectly fine with an 8GB big file without any problem.. how to optimize? that depends on what you use, are you using modifiers? If yes you can always hide them from viewport to save on performance, you can hide objects you are not using as well, if you are using the dense object, try to decimate them into more simple shapes... these things should help your CPU, in terms of GPU you should try to go to settings go to preferences and try to change system and viewport quality settings

Comment: i often use subdivision and solidify modifiers, but on smaller objects that arent as consequential I've been using the smooth surface thingy in viewport, and I've been using decimate a little, thank you, but it seems even when i hide all the objects its still just as slow as long as the objects exist in the directory